How to prove the sliding window algorithm works to find the largest non repeating substring
Doing the leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/ I found this solution:
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        left = 0
        right = 0 
        currstring= ""
        maxlength=0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            
            while s[i] in currstring: 
                left+=1
                currstring = currstring[1::]
            currstring+=s[i]
            right+=1
            maxlength = max(maxlength, right-left)
        return maxlength


However I wanted to prove that this algorithm works using induction and I don't know how to prove it.
I got the induction hypothesis

P(n): For any string of length n, the algorithm gives the size of the longest non repeating substring.

BASE CASE, N=0:
It gives 0, so it is correct
INDUCTION STEP N=k.
Assuming P(k) is true: s_k is a substring of s_k+1 then P(k) <= P(k+1).
Given a string of length k+1, we can have 2 cases:

The k+1th character is not in the longest substring, therefore P(k+1)=P(k) and by the induction hypothesis the algorithm gives the length of the longest substring

(However, if the k+1th term is in the longest substring I don't know if this is valid: )

The k+1th term is in the longest substring. Then,if P(k)=l,  the last k+1-l terms must be different.The, I'm stuck here.

But I don't know if this goes anywhere or I should take a completely different approach.

Try proving the loop invariant: at each iteration, left is the farthest one can expand the window to the left starting at index i.

Could you give me a hint please?
